# MySQL database not catching up with INSERT statements

Tags: mysql, ubuntu, myisam, mysql-8.0

I'm having troubles with my MySql server. It's used mainly for storing production logs, but unfortunately it seems like it it too slow and i dont know if there is something i could do to improve it.Sometimes there is even few hours of delay. The `log` database is working on MyISAM engine.

Here is mytop output:
[image: mytop output]

Comment: change the table to innodb, for the rest we don't know nothing about hardware/ size of tables, structure of tables and indexes

Comment: @nbk I would prefer not to change the engine.  CPU is Intel Xeon-E 2386G, Hard drive is Samsung PM9A1 512GB.  Table size is 122817 MB, one index for one field with BTREE index method.

Comment: usually you start with mysql error log and see if there are problems, then you repair the table. MyIsam is old and you should really think about innodb if the other things don't help

Comment: If I had high-throughput logging at such a rate, I wouldn't save it to an SQL database. It's bound to create a "logjam" (pun intended). Instead, use a real logging technology. Open source products include [Graylog](https://graylog.org/) or [Grafana Loki](https://grafana.com/oss/loki/) or [LogStash](https://www.elastic.co/logstash/). Proprietary products include [Seq](https://datalust.co/seq) or [Datadog](https://www.datadoghq.com/).

Comment: @nbk It was first thing i did and there are no errors.

Comment: @BillKarwin Is it really that big rate? It shouldnt reach more than 200 queries per second. I cant really change logging technology right now.

Comment: then change the engine

Comment: If you have so many requests queued up, then the traffic is greater than your database can handle with your current system. Since you've already said you can't change the engine and can't change the logging technology, then the only other things to change are the hardware (i.e. get faster CPU and storage), or split up the traffic over multiple MySQL servers (i.e. sharding), or else reduce the traffic (i.e. don't log so much).

Comment: Additional DB information request, please. 
OS, Version? 
RAM size, # cores, any SSD or NVME devices on MySQL Host server? 
Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
From your SSH login root, Text results of: 
A) SELECT COUNT(*) FROM information_schema.tables;
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after minimum 24 hours UPTIME
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST; 
E) STATUS;  not SHOW STATUS, just STATUS;
G) SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS; 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide INSERT speed up suggestions.

Comment: Post TEXT data on justpaste.it and share the links. 
Additional very helpful OS information includes - please,  
htop            1st page, if available, TERMINATE, 
top -b -n 1  for most active apps, 
top -b -n 1 -H  for details on your mysql threads memory and cpu usage, 
ulimit -a       for list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device & core/cpu count, 
df -h  for Used - Free space by device, 
df -i  for inode info by device, 
free -h  for Used - Free  Mem: and Swap:, 
cat /proc/meminfo includes VMallocUused,  
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: @WilsonHauck Only thing i cant provide is SHOW GLOBAL STATUS; since i restarted mysql hoping it would help (it didnt).  OS is Ubuntu 21.10. RAM 32 GB ECC 3200 MHz. Drive is 2×512 GB SSD NVMe Samsung PM9A1. CPU Intel Xeon-E 2386G - 6c/12t - 3.5 GHz/4.7 GHz.

https://justpaste.it/anx0e

Comment: Please post SHOW GLOBAL STATUS after at least 24 hours uptime that includes one full working day.

Comment: @Alkyone  Please also post TEXT results of  
SELECT COUNT(*), sum(data_length), sum(index_length), sum(data_free) FROM information_schema.tables;   Thank you.

Comment: Is your Ubuntu Server running in PowerSave mode?

Comment: @WilsonHauck There you go: https://justpaste.it/8qbfz

As for PowerSave, what do you mean exactly? Its hosted on OVH so nothing like that should be enabled.

Comment: @Alkyone  Here is a URL for powersave investigation on UBUNTU server.  You may have to ask OVH what your settings are.  If you are in PowerSave mode, more than 10% of processing power is throttled back to reduce power bill, typically.  QPS will be less than the potential when in Full Power full time.  Your analysis is in process.

Comment: This is the URL that should have been included in last comment.  https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/ubuntu-unleashed-2014/9780133475654/ch01lev2sec10.html#:~:text=Click%20the%20Power%20icon%20in,situations%20(see%20Figure%201.11).   
my apologies.

Comment: @Alkyone  I see your ulimit -a report indicates you are limited to Open Files of 1024 at the OS level.  Within MYSQL your request is for 10,000 Open_Files_limit.  To reduce Opened_Tables reported in Show Global Status, we need to increase the maximum reported by ulimit -a to 14000.  You may be able to do this from UBUN Command Prompt with  ulimit -n 14000 (enter).  Check it with ulimit -a report.  If you can not change it, please ask OVH to do this for you to avoid Table Open Thrashing in MySQL.

Comment: If we can accomplish this, to make this change persist across OS STOP/START, the following is a guide that should be helpful.  https://glassonionblog.wordpress.com/2013/01/27/increase-ulimit-and-file-descriptors-limit/    You need 14,000 for your present limit not the 500,000 as listed in this example.

Comment: @WilsonHauck I was able to change limit of open files, unfortunately it didnt help, i'm still maxed out at 120 qps.

Comment: Great, See ANSWER just posted for additional details to consider, please.  You may find QPS has inched up after 60 minutes - your dynamic changes apply to NEW CONNECTIONS.

Answer (score 0):

Observation from data provided,

There appears to be a process running unattended-upgr (upgrade) that could
be contributing to some of your frustration.

Select_scan events at RPHr of 1,299 could be minimized with index to
reduce runtime to create results.  Drop long_query_time by 1 second a day until you have results in your Slow Query Log to be corrected by creating an appropriate index.

Rate Per Second = RPS

Suggestions to consider for your my.cnf [mysqld] section

```
key_cache_age_threshold=7200  # from 300 (seconds) to age out MyISAM data to reduce key_reads RPS of 2.01.
key_cache_division_limit=50  # from 100 to have HOT / WARM storage and further reduce key_reads RPS of 2.01.
net_buffer_length=98304  # from 16384 to reduce packet in / out counts
read_rnd_buffer_size=16384  # from 262144 to reduce handler_read_rnd_next RPS of 10,825. 
slow_query_log=ON  # from OFF for investigation and index creation, when missing.
```

There are many more opportunities to improve performance.  View profile please.

Comment: @Alkyone  Any news on suggestions being applied?

Comment: I'm kind of resigned. Nothing changed after all changes you suggested. I dont see any qps change no matter what i change. CPU, RAM and Disk utilization is very low, yet these INSERT's are so slow.

Comment: Please post the A) COMPLETE query doing the INSERT and TEXT results of B) SHOW CREATE TABLE (tbl_name); and TEXT results of C) SHOW TABLE STATUS WHERE name LIKE "(tbl_name)"; for analysis.

Comment: https://justpaste.it/cusbg

Comment: Please review this URL from MySQL 8.0  - https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-delayed.html - and consider removing the word DELAYED to avoid every insert generating a WARNING message that is being ignored anyway.  This may improve your QPS rate.

Comment: Please  SHOW COUNT(*) WARNINGS;  to see what the current count is on your system.

Comment: Warning count is just 0.

Comment: @Alkyone  Do you have flexibility to use Skype.com and talk with me in English?  Will be out of my office next 7 hours.  Skype ID is  wlhauck@aol.com  in Birmingham, AL  USA

Comment: Thanks for all your help but i gave up. I switched to InnoDB and it works properly.

Comment: Wonderful.  Likely performance is much better overall.

Answer (score 0):

- InnoDB is faster at concurrent `INSERTs`.  Switch to InnoDB.
- In particular, that Processlist probably implies something else is happening with the table.  Again, InnoDB is better at handling concurrency.
- If practical, batch the inserts -- A single `INSERT` with 100 rows runs about 10 times as fast as 100 single-row `INSERTs`.
- Having lots of indexes on the log table slows things down some.
- The use of [*Summary Tables*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/summarytables) may avoid the need for lots of indexes.
- See [*High speed ingestion*](https://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table) for even better performance (within MySQL/MariaDB).
- MyISAM has been removed from MySQL 8.0 and all "clustering" configurations.  That is, your next upgrade may *force* you to change to InnoDB.

Comment: Also make sure to upgrade to 8.0.35 to get the fix for INSERT performance regressions in InnoDB. See https://smalldatum.blogspot.com/2023/11/fixing-bug-109595-makes-mysql-almost-4x.html